# RTF GetPropertyValue issues

Tags: c#, wpf, rtf

Attempting to have a highlight button on a text box, the highlight functionality works. The issue comes in with having the highlight button show that text is highlighted, I want it to appear pressed but when I select text that is highlighted, GetPropertyValue does not return a value.

Working highlight method:

```
        private void HighlightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        richEditControl.Focus();
        var currentColour = richEditControl.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty);
        if (currentColour == null || currentColour == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            richEditControl.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
        }
        else
        {
            richEditControl.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, null);
        }

        UpdateButtonStates();
        }
```

snippet from UpdateButtonStates, that isn't working.

```
        var currentColour = richEditControl.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty);
        if (currentColour == null || currentColour == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            HighlightButton.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            HighlightButton.IsChecked = true;
        }
```

Comment: What is HighlightButton and what exactly isn't working...? Please provide a full repo of your issue.

Comment: i tested, work.